# HEVC with Alpha Encoding on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, frontend, html5-video, encode, hevc

I know, this question has been asked before, but most of the answers to them are very old.

Actually, I am developing a website which uses transparent videos. So, I am using .webm format for them. However, as you know it is not possible to run .webm with transparency on Apple products. So, after researching on internet(stackoverflow etc), I found a solution that I should convert my video into a series of PNGs and then convert them into HEVC with alpha channel. However, according to the research I done, only the Apple hardware can properly encode HEVC with alpha channel.

I am a newbie to these codecs and formats stuff. So, I think that I read somewhere that latest versions of FFMPEG can also encode HEVC with alpha. However, being a noob I can't figure out any way to write a command for this purpose. Being a beginner with almost non-existent skills in this field of expertise, it is nearly impossible for me to understand the documentations correctly. I also tried using shutterencoder and some other tools but failed.

Although, there is a quicktime .mov solution but with that the file size becomes too large for my 10 sec video, almost 334 mb and as you know this size is too large for a animation video on a landing-page style basic website.

So, now my question is there any way to properly encode HEVC with alpha on Windows or Linux to maintain transparency ?

If this is not possible, then is there any other way to create such transparent videos on Windows or Linux which can be played on browsers of Apple devices ?

I am stuck on this for 3 days, So, any type of help is greatly regarded. I am also providing the link to my videos, if someone wants to take a closer look on codes and formats of these videos : [Videos Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ace42db188a534f3b9595c28a70fd53b20230620170351/5a8b84)

P.S : if anyone with a mac device can encode these transparent videos for me, then that would be best and I shall be very grateful to you

Comment: ffmpeg can encode HEVC w/ alpha but only *on* a Mac using the `hevc_videotoolbox` encoder.

Answer (score 0):

If you got access to Adobe Software you could install the og plugin from fnordware.com. It is free, pretty popular and can export webm's with transparency. Don't know how reliably etc. (Curiously enough, it won't READ the exported clip's transparency when played back in Premiere or After Effects.)

Comment: Link: https://fnordware.com/WebM/